# CATransform3DMakeRotation anchorpoint and position in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, catransform3d

Hi I am trying to rotate a triangle shaped CAShapeLayer. The northPole CAShapeLayer is defined in a custom UIView class. I have two functions in the class one to setup the layer properties and one to animate the rotation. The rotation animate works fine but after the rotation completes it reverts back to the original position. I want the layer to stay at the angle given (positionTo = 90.0) after the rotation animation.

I am trying to set the position after the transformation to retain the correct position after the animation. I have also tried to get the position from the presentation() method but this has been unhelpful. I have read many articles on frame, bounds, anchorpoints but I still cannot seem to make sense of why this transformation rotation is not working.

```
private func setupNorthPole(shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer) {
    shapeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.width / 2 - triangleWidth / 2, y: self.bounds.height / 2 - triangleHeight, width: triangleWidth, height: triangleHeight)//self.bounds
    let polePath = UIBezierPath()
    polePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: triangleHeight))
    polePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth / 2, y: 0))
    polePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: triangleHeight))
    shapeLayer.path = polePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
```

The animate function:

```
private func animate() {
    let positionTo = CGFloat(DegreesToRadians(value: degrees))
    let rotate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotate.fromValue = 0.0
    rotate.toValue = positionTo //CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
    rotate.duration = 0.5
    northPole.add(rotate, forKey: nil)
    let present = northPole.presentation()!
    print("presentation position x " + "\(present.position.x)")
    print("presentation position y " + "\(present.position.y)")


    CATransaction.begin()
    northPole.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(positionTo, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    northPole.position = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width / 2, y: self.bounds.height / 2)
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: Okay, sorry about my bad answer earlier. I'm just going to suggest that you drop the `present`, drop the `begin`, drop the `commit`, and read my book to learn how to do a rotation using CABasicAnimation: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_using_a_cabasicanimation

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, in the custom UIView class I had to override layoutSubviews() with the following:

```
  super.layoutSubviews()
  let northPoleTransform: CATransform3D = northPole.transform
  northPole.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
  setupNorthPole(northPole)  
  northPole.transform = northPoleTransform
```